# React-Native ImageEditor.cropImage shows no picture

Tags: image, react-native, split, crop

I've been trying to cut a picture into several parts for hours now.
I thought it would work with `ImageEditor.cropImage`. Apparently I'm using the function wrong, or it doesn't do what I expect it to do.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, or recommend a package I can use. Thank you.

My attempt:

```
  const cropData = {
                     offset: {x: 25, y: 25},
                     size: {width: 250, height: 250},
                     displaySize: {width: 250, height: 250},
                     resizeMode: 'contain',
                   };
```

later..

```
ImageEditor.cropImage(require('../resources/images/pictures/categoryOne/c1b1.jpg'),
cropData);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's exactly you want to make.? do you need to crop image through the image picker or something different then i can definitely help you.

Comment: I want to cut an image into two halves and display only one half.
As an example I have this picture: [link](https://i.ibb.co/hLfh12x/example1.png)
but I only want to display the following: [link](https://i.ibb.co/yVLPhxx/example2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue not with ImageEditor.cropImage but with CSS

```
<View style={styles.topLeftView}>
  <Image
    style={styles.topLeftImage}
    source={require('../resources/images/pictures/categoryOne/c1b1.jpg')}
    resizeMode="contain"
  />
</View>
```

Style

```
topLeftView: {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  overflow: 'hidden',
},
topLeftImage: {
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
},
```